# Selenium script in C# does not find element

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, nunit

I recorded a script using the Selenium Chrome IDE, and exported it as a C#, NUnit class.  When I run the test in Visual Studio, it fails to find an element.  It's clearly there on the screen and if I run it using the Selenium IDE it works perfectly.  Here is my test;

```
[Test]
Public void login()
{
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.oracle.com/uk/cloud/sign-in.html");
    driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
    driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("I accept all cookies"), 5).Click();
    }
}
```

I have copied an extension to let me wait for the element to be present more easily;

```
public static class WebDriverExtensions
{
    public static IWebElement FindElement(this IWebDriver driver, By by, int timeoutInSeconds)
    {
        if (timeoutInSeconds > 0)
        {
            var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutInSeconds));
            return wait.Until(drv => drv.FindElement(by));
        }
        return driver.FindElement(by);
    }
}
```

I also tried;

```
driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("call"), 5).Click();
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT ***
Exception Message;

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException : Timed out after 5 seconds
  ----> OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException : no such element: Unable to 
locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".call"}
  (Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.83)
```

Stack trace;

```
DefaultWait`1.ThrowTimeoutException(String exceptionMessage, Exception lastException)
DefaultWait`1.Until[TResult](Func`2 condition)
WebDriverExtensions.FindElement(IWebDriver driver, By by, Int32 timeoutInSeconds) line 16
LoginTest.login() line 54
--NoSuchElementException
RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(String mechanism, String value)
RemoteWebDriver.FindElementByClassName(String className)
<>c__DisplayClass20_0.<ClassName>b__0(ISearchContext context)
By.FindElement(ISearchContext context)
RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(By by)
<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<FindElement>b__0(IWebDriver drv) line 16
DefaultWait`1.Until[TResult](Func`2 condition)
```

Comment: what is the exception message and stack trace?

Comment: Edited Post with both @GregBurghardt

Comment: Your button is in an iframe - you need to switch frames to access it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cookie accept button is in an `iframe`.

With webdriver you need to switch your driver into that frame to be able to access the elements within.

You need to:

1. identify the frmae
2. Switch to the frame
3. Click your button
4. switch back to the "default content" (the main bit) of the page

As for a wait strategy - There are explicit waits and implicit waits. For simplicity I've thrown an an implicit wait. This is just simpler and less code. (there are lots of [tutorials](https://www.guru99.com/implicit-explicit-waits-selenium.html) on there on this)

I've checked your site and it looks like that frame has a good title.

This xpath looks good to get the frame:

```
//iframe[@title='TrustArc Cookie Consent Manager']
```

Putting it together for you:

```
            var driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.Url = "https://www.oracle.com/uk/cloud/sign-in.html";
            
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);

            var iframe = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//iframe[@title='TrustArc Cookie Consent Manager']"));
            driver.SwitchTo().Frame(iframe);
            driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("I accept all cookies")).Click();
            driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
```

That works for me.
Any problems please let me know.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks for you help Rich, greatly appreciated.